# LoadError when using heroku db:push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When i use "heroku db:push" to transfer my local data to heroku,i got this error message:

**Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: no such file to load -- sequel/adapters/mysql2**

I already install the mysql2 gem, and i am using rvm with ruby 1.9.2 in Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the most current version of Sequel?  mysql2 support wasn't added until 3.15.0.

Comment: thanks for your reply,i installed sequal again ,and this time i got sequel (3.15.0, 3.13.0) installed,when i run heroku db:push again ,i got this error message:Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> Gem::LoadError: can't activate sequel (= 3.15.0, runtime) for [], already activated sequel-3.13.0 for ["taps-0.3.11"],i try to uninstall sequal but failed,how can i fix it???

Comment: i thought i face a touth problem,i find that rails3 is using mysql2,and taps using sequal 3.13,but only sequal 3.15 support mysql2,is there any solution to this problem??? great thanks!!

Comment: You'll have to wait for a new release of taps that depends on a more recent version of Sequel.  Or you can modify the taps gem spec to require Sequel 3.15.0 instead of 3.13.0.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am trying now too! If I figure something out I'll post,

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use the original "mysql" gem still with rails3 instead of "mysql2" to get around this problem.

Comment: sure i tried this ,but when i run "bundle install",i got some error.. which ruby version do u use?

Answer (score 0):

Taps is still not compatible with sequel 3.15 which has mysql2 support. So mysql2 adapter won't work heroku db:pull or db:push commands. But I got it working by using the old mysql adapter. i was facing problems because my mysql adapter wasn't configured properly. If you are on 64 bit macOSX. Try uninstalling mysql adapter and reinstalling it using:
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

might be old news, but make sure you are a) in the projects root folder and b) in the correct rvm gemset!